# Showing a webpage in popup in Angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-interface, modal-dialog

I'm developing an Angular App with some page which has a table. In the table there is a row with a URL, Accept/Reject buttons. Based on the information in the page with the URL, I must accept or reject. I don't want this page to open in a new window. Is there a way to show this page in a modal window in Angular ? All I found is showing some json data etc but not a page.

Comment: you can use an iframe

Answer (score 0):

[AngularUI bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) has a ngModal module, you can use that to display the table in a modal pop-up with buttons and what not. Check it out.

Comment: Question is how to display a webpage in a modal popup. Not a table. My table has rows with URLs in one of the columns. On clicking the URL, the webpage of the URL must be shown in a popup. Thanks for responding though.

Comment: It does not matter, you still can use ngModal for that.

Comment: The URL is not on my domain. I tried this example - http://www.bootply.com/61676 It won't work for URL on different domain.

Comment: Did you try to use the iframe?

Comment: Yeah, I got X-Frame Deny from the other URL. The other URL is also hosted by us, but we do not want to allow X-Frame on that.